# Dynamically add a jtable to jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java.

I'm trying to build a CRUD program. Now, I try to read the data from the database and display them in a `jtable`. So every time I will create a new table and add it to the `jpanel`. But the program does not show the table when update. Can someone help me?

```
package com.accsoftware.ui;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import com.accsoftware.common.Table1;
import com.accsoftware.util.DataHandler;


public class SearchAndDisplayPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9078860779973523031L;

    public SearchAndDisplayPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        chooseTableButtonGroup = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        date = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        date1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        displayPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        generateReport = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Search = new javax.swing.JButton();
        chooseTablePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        table1RadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        jLabel1.setText("Start:");

        jLabel2.setText("End:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout displayPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(displayPanel);
        displayPanel.setLayout(displayPanelLayout);
        displayPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            displayPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        displayPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            displayPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 173, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        generateReport.setText("Generate Report");
        generateReport.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                generateReportActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Search.setText("Search");
        Search.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SearchActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        chooseTableButtonGroup.add(table1RadioButton);
        table1RadioButton.setText("Table1");

        chooseTableButtonGroup.add(jRadioButton2);
        jRadioButton2.setText("Table2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout chooseTablePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(chooseTablePanel);
        chooseTablePanel.setLayout(chooseTablePanelLayout);
        chooseTablePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            chooseTablePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(chooseTablePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(table1RadioButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        chooseTablePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            chooseTablePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(chooseTablePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(chooseTablePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(table1RadioButton)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton2))
                .addGap(0, 6, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(displayPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 149, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 79, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(date1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(24, 24, 24))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(chooseTablePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(generateReport)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(Search)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(date1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(displayPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(generateReport)
                        .addComponent(Search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(chooseTablePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void generateReportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Date start = dateToString(date);
        Date end = dateToString(date1);
        String table = table1RadioButton.isSelected()?"Table1":"Table2";
        List result = DataHandler.readAll(table, start, end);

        int col = table1RadioButton.isSelected()?7:10;

        Object[][] data = new Object[result.size()][col];

        if(table.equalsIgnoreCase("Table1")){
            int id = 0;
            for(Object element:result){
                Table1 table1 = (Table1) element;
                data[id][0] = table1.getDate();
                data[id][1] = table1.getItem();
                data[id][2] = table1.getFee();
                data[id][3] = table1.getGst();
                data[id][4] = table1.getVehicle();
                data[id][5] = table1.getWages();
                data[id][6] = table1.getStationary();
                id++;           

            }
            String[] columnNames = { "Date", "Reference/Item", "Cost", "GST",
                    "Vehicle", "Wages", "Stationary" };

            JTable displayTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
            this.displayPanel.add(displayTable);
            this.displayPanel.revalidate();
            this.displayPanel.repaint();            
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Date dateToString(com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser date){
        return new Date(date.getDate().getYear(),
                date.getDate().getMonth(), date.getDate().getDay());
    } 
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton Search;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup chooseTableButtonGroup;
    private javax.swing.JPanel chooseTablePanel;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser date;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser date1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel displayPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton generateReport;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton table1RadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `GroupLayout` which requires horizontal and vertical sequential groups when adding components. This type of work is best left to UI builders.

Create a single `JTable` when the application is initialized rather than adding multiple tables. Update the `TableModel` when data retrieval is required. Use the mutable `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: Post an [Short Self Contained Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/) so we can see what the code looks like

Comment: I tried to add a new JTable to one of the panel contained by the parent panel. Then show the new table to the user.

Comment: You using `GroupLayout`, (thought you might be) let me update the answer - sigh!

Comment: The major downside to using netbeans is that it makes you less familiar with the UI code

Comment: +1, `Hi, I tried you way, it still does not work...` - then your code is wrong. Updating the model of the table is the best and easiest way to do this. You can update the table with any TableModel it does not specifically need to be a DefaultTableModel for this approach to work. `I tried to add a new JTable to one of the panel contained by the parent panel.` you were specifically asked not to do this. You haven't posted a SSCCE yet so we can't help you further.